# Azure Blob sharing SAS time window

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I trying to share blob for one minute with this code:

```
    public static void CdnInit()
    {
        StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
        BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }

    public static string GetSharedBlobUrl(ContainerType conteiner, string fileName)
    {
        CloudBlob blob = BlobClient.GetBlobReference(containerNameByType(conteiner) + @"/" + fileName);
        return StorageUrl + "/" + containerNameByType(conteiner) + "/" + fileName + blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        });

    }
```

But redirecting to generated url giving me this error:

`Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour`

I tried many time combinations but the same result.

Comment: The resulting SAS URL will give you the expiry time within the query parameters.  What expiry time does that show, and is it more than 1 hour from now?  Could it be that your local machine (where you are running this code) is running an hour ahead of time?

Comment: Time on my machine was set up incorrectly. Thanks for pointing to that!

Answer (score -1):

Try using DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.UtcNow, thats the problem. UtcNow gives date according to GMT and that could be more than 1 hour time as per your local time.

Comment: This is wrong answer. In Windows Azure everything is in UTC/GMT so the date/time must always be in UTC.

Comment: Oops, yea my bad, I of course read following http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure.aspx